# I want to do this sql on Ruby on Rails with distinct or group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do this sql on Ruby on Rails (with include or joins), I have this:

```
@info = Ranking.all(:joins => :user, :select => "ranking.idNick, ranking.nickname, user.data1, user.data2" ).
```

It works but without grouping or distinct when I use `@info` in my view.

```
select
  ranking.id, 
  ranking.nickname, 
  user.data1, 
  user.data2 
from  
  ranking 
  inner join user
where ranking.idNick = user.id
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Where do you want to include the group or distinct? What is the end result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: that sql works well, list only one record per nickname, but in rails mode (first code) list to many record per nickname, i don't want to repeat records. thanks

Comment: If you only want one row, why not group and order as you need to and then use `.limit(1)` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset